# Identify modified blobs from storage account changefeed

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently consuming the changefeed on Azure storage account and would like to distinguish between blobs created (uploaded) and those that are just modified.

In the example below I upload a blob (agent-diag.txt) and then edit the file (add some text).

In both cases it raises 'BlobCreated', there seems no concept of 'BlobUpdated'.

From MS Doc: The following event types are captured in the change feed records:

BlobCreated
BlobDeleted
BlobPropertiesUpdated
BlobSnapshotCreated

BlobPropertiesUpdated is recorded if the meta data or tags etc are changed. But if the file is modified I can't see any way to identify this. Any ideas?

Operation Name: PutBlob
Api: Azure.Storage.Blobs.ChangeFeed.BlobChangeFeedEventData
Subject: /blobServices/default/containers/myblobs/blobs/agent-diag.txt
Event Type: BlobCreated
Event Time: 17/11/2021 23:25:42 +00:00

Operation Name: PutBlob
Api: Azure.Storage.Blobs.ChangeFeed.BlobChangeFeedEventData
Subject: /blobServices/default/containers/myblobs/blobs/agent-diag.txt
Event Type: BlobCreated
Event Time: 17/11/2021 23:26:07 +00:00

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.ChangeFeed;



namespace Changefeed
{
    class Program
    {
        const string conString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=BlahBlah";

        public static async Task<List<BlobChangeFeedEvent>> ChangeFeedAsync(string connectionString)
        {
            // Get a new blob service client.
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

            // Get a new change feed client.
            BlobChangeFeedClient changeFeedClient = blobServiceClient.GetChangeFeedClient();

            List<BlobChangeFeedEvent> changeFeedEvents = new List<BlobChangeFeedEvent>();

            // Get all the events in the change feed. 
            await foreach (BlobChangeFeedEvent changeFeedEvent in changeFeedClient.GetChangesAsync())
            {
                changeFeedEvents.Add(changeFeedEvent);
            }

            return changeFeedEvents;
        }



        public static void showEventData(List<BlobChangeFeedEvent> changeFeedEvents)
        {
            foreach (BlobChangeFeedEvent changeFeedEvent in changeFeedEvents)
            {
                string subject = changeFeedEvent.Subject;
                string eventType = changeFeedEvent.EventType.ToString();
                string eventTime = changeFeedEvent.EventTime.ToString();

                string api = changeFeedEvent.EventData.ToString();
                string operation = changeFeedEvent.EventData.BlobOperationName.ToString();


                Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + subject + "\n" +
                "Event Type: " + eventType + "\n" +
                "Event Time: " + eventTime + "\n" +
                "Operation Name: " + operation + "\n" +
                "Api: " + api);
            }
        }


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            List<BlobChangeFeedEvent> feedlist =  ChangeFeedAsync(conString).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine("Feedlist :" + feedlist.Count());

            showEventData(feedlist);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer [Change feed support in Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-change-feed?tabs=azure-portal)

Answer (score 0):

Each blob has 2 system defined properties - created date and last modified which tells you when a blob was created and when it was last modified respectively.

When a blob is created, both of these properties will have the same value. However when the same blob is overwritten (i.e. content updated), only the last modified value is changed.

What you could do is use these properties to identify whether a new blob is created or content of an existing blob is updated.

You would still work with `BlobCreated` event. One additional step you would need to do is fetch the properties of the blob and compare these two properties to make the distinction.

Comment: Thanks, tried something along those lines but becomes messy trying to reverse engineer events based on the dates. Guess I'm surprised there isn't an BlobUpdated event that has the version ID's etc